# How do i set a variable using a conditional statement?

Tags: jquery, variables, var, conditional-statements

I have a series of functions that i am passing the same variable to, however i want this variable's value to change dependent on the window height. Setting var X works fine, though when i remove it and attempt to designate its value through a conditional statement it doesnt read:

```
<script>

var viewportHeight = $(window).height();

$(function() {
  $(window).resize(function() {
    if (viewportHeight >= 600) {
         var X = 100;
       }
    if (viewportHeight < 600) {
         var X = 50;
       }
   });
});
</script>
```

This of course would be placed within the same script tags as the scripts im affecting, as i dont believe its possible to set a global var this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the x variable to global, try like this

```
 var x; // global vairable 
$(function() {

  $(window).resize(function() {
    if (viewportHeight >= 600) {
        x=100;
       }
    if (viewportHeight < 600) {
         X = 50;
       }
   });
});
```

Comment: If X is declared within $(function(){}) block it wont be accessible outside that anonymous function. So it's better to declare it outside of this function so it can be accessed in non dom ready function. :)

Comment: and second use of X(x=100;) is in lowercase which is not the same as uppercase variable declaration X. Please update that too. :)

Comment: Thanks for the tip but the function still doesnt work. Did i do something wrong?

Comment: I tried the same function with just a print ("whatever") in it and it works fine, why does setting a variables value not work?

Comment: nm, i put var in the function block by accident doh!